# Angular, calling function in active route

Tags: angular

If a menu button is clicked and it is currently the active route I want to be able to call a function within that active's route component.

So something like this (pseudo code)

```
if (e.target.name == activeRoute) {
    activeRoute.callFunctionOnComponent()
}
```

This is my current code for the navigation

```
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">home</a>
  <a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">about</a>
  <a routerLink="/work" routerLinkActive="active">work</a>
</nav>
<main >
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

Comment: you want to call function in component when route related to that component get active ?

Comment: When a route is active, that particular component is loaded and shown in the `router-outlet` space. So if you want to call a components function, then you dont need to explicitly write `callFunctionOnComponent`. The calls in that html will be redirected to the component itself.

Comment: yes @PranayRana I want to call the function in the component when route related to that component gets active

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this?

Comment: Yes @CharlieNorris see my comment below

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you well, so you want to call function when you click on the link where you currently are.

So, it is possible to do it like:

```
<a routerLink="/work" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="checkRoute('/work')">work</a>
```

And inside the `checkRoute()` function do check:

```
checkRoute(link) {
    if (this.router.url === link) {
        callYourFunction(...)
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok but how to a call a function in the active component? ..I need to get the reference object of the active component,

Comment: I needed to add this to the `(activate)="routedComponent = $event"`  on `<router-outlet (activate)="routedComponent = $event"></router-outlet>` then I could reference the component

Answer (score 0):

not clear from your question but you need to do like this

```
ngOnInit() {//implement onInit in your component and write code in ngOninit
  this.router.events
      .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
     .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
    .subscribe((event) => {
     console.log('NavigationEnd:', event);
  });
}
```

Ans based on : [Dynamic page titles in Angular 2 with router events](https://toddmotto.com/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events)

and if you are using bootstrap css then in html as below

```
<a class="nav-link"
[routerLink]="['home']"
[routerLinkActive]="['active']">
Home
</a>
```

Comment: But then how do I call the function in the active route component?

Comment: @colouredFunk - have you tried out code given , that you need to include it in your component